Как реализовать подобие NAS на винде?
Вопрос о том как расшарить мои диски с пк в сеть. Что именно требуется: получить доступ к дискам хотя бы с телефона а лучше вообще с любого устройства (пк, телефон и иные), возможно какая то программа есть.
Не отдельный NAS и вот почему: это моя рабочая станция в которой стоит уйма дисков необходимые именно в ней, просто вырвать диски и поставить в nas не вариант, но файлы с нее мне нужны перманентно и из любой точки мира. Программы по типу TeamWiever, Anydesk и другие для удаленного управления не вариант т.к. имеют оооочень сильно ограниченную скорость передачи и ограниченное по времени подключение. Да anydesk вроде удобный, есть и на пк и на телефон, и на пк даже устанавливать не обязательно на скорость передачи файлов 4 MB/с меня категорически не устраивает. (да именно мегабайты а не мегабиты.)

Ну поставьте ftp сервер, расшарьте через него нужные каталоги и качайте оттуда что нужно. Или вам не только скачивать нужно?

Ещё можно nginx под винду поставить и тогда любой браузер сможет качать файлы.

нет, мне нужно не только скачивать, а полноценно взаимодействовать с файлами.

@BELAFU, разверните что-нибудь типа NextCloud и используйте на клиентах Desktop, либо Mobile (IOS/Android)
